# Rexeg matching for hex commands containing special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex to match any of a list of hex commands e.g.

`\x0a\x0b` or `\x76\x69`or `\x5e\x6a\x56\x02` ...

My initial approach was to use:

`re.compile(b"|".join([hex_list])`

However, as I do not know what the hex strings contain until the program is executed this can cause a problem when the hex code for special regex characters such as `(` (ascii code`\x28`) are passed in.

What I am looking for is something akin to the raw string which will allow me to strictly match the characters themselves.

Comment: Regex, not Rexeg

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape a literal string you want to use as/in a pattern:

```
re.compile(b"|".join([re.escape(h) for h in hex_list])
```